# How do I control indentation of array initializers with clang-format?

Tags: c++, clang-format

Sometimes clang-format does this :

```
SomeType VariableName[] = {Thing1,
                           Thing2,
                           Thing3}
```

and sometimes clang-format does this :

```
SomeType VariableName[] = {
   Thing1,
   Thing2,
   Thing3}
```

and a single character change can make it switch between.

Is there any way to control which it does?

I'm building from the latest git source, so the latest options are available.

Comment: Could you give more information about what kind of single character change could make it switch between? Such information will be helpful to me to find out the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to create a little tiny case for this question, but it works fine without problem.

Comment: The single character change was changing PointerAlignment from Right to Middle.

Comment: I don't understand "works fine without problem". I wasn't claiming that there was a bug. It's just that I would prefer to always get the second style.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34362422/108802), `clang-format` in some step puts as much as possible on a single line, and applies the `ColumnLimit` on that.

That would explain the switching between behaviors.

[One way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39287832/108802) to prevent this could be to set `ColumnLimit` to 0, with the cost of removing all automatic wrapping. I think it's worth the cost, I'm sure other don't agree.

Answer (score -3):

`clang-format` provide a way for user to specify a single property when format the code, such as whether `tab` is allowed, what is the `tabwidth`.

You could use the following way to tell `clang-format` to use a customized property.

```
  $clang-format -style="{BaseonStype: llvm, IndentWidth: 8}"
  $clang-format -style=HAND_WRITTEN_FORMAT_FILENAME
  $clang-format -style=llvm  #builtin styles.
```

You could get an idea about what property you could customize in the [file](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/Format_8cpp_source.html) from line `171` to line `266`.

Comment: I know how to change the properties. I've studied http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html carefully, and it seems to be up to date with respect to the source. No property seems to control this behavior, although a smaller ColumnLimit will often change it from the first style to the second style.