# How to wrap struct initializer in clang-format?

Tags: c, clang-format

Take this example before clang-format runs:

```
struct ApplicationState app_state = {
    .signal = {
        .use_crash_handler = true,
        .use_abort_handler = true,
    },
    .exit_code_on_error = {
        .python = 0,
    }
};
```

After running, clang-format applies as follows:

```
struct ApplicationState app_state = {.signal =
                                             {
                                                     .use_crash_handler = true,
                                                     .use_abort_handler = true,
                                             },
                                     .exit_code_on_error = {
                                             .python = 0,
                                     }};
```

Is there a way to add a newline after the brace, before the struct member so it's more like the first example and not like the second?

Comment: The first version is **before** clang-format runs. The question is how to maintain this format and prevent the awkward second example.

Comment: I don't know clang but with AStyle I'm almost sure there's a comment you can put on top of your structure to disable auto-format. Try to check if something similar exists for clang.

Comment: @TimF, There is. See [Disabling Formatting on a Piece of Code](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#disabling-formatting-on-a-piece-of-code)

Comment: @TimF, of course formatting can be disabled as needed as a last resort. Ideally use of this is kept to a minimum though, and formatting the struct in the Q is standard C99, nothing unusual.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656800/clang-format-line-breaks

Comment: Have you found a configuration solution? I'm facing similar issues with my C++ code. Sure I could use comments and what not, but that just isn't pretty.

Comment: @Arsenal added an answer. While it's a bit of a workaround for this limitation in clang-format in practice it's OK.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that. Maybe I should write a feature request for an option to handle this...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Currently `clang-format` doesn't have a useful way of controlling this *(as of version 14.0)*.

While `BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: All` does force wrapping (see @eric-backus' s answer), it impacts formatting in many other places too, unrelated to struct declaration.

You *can* however, workaround this simply by using a trailing comma.

---

Before:

```c
struct ApplicationState app_state = {.signal =
                                             {
                                                     .use_crash_handler = true,
                                                     .use_abort_handler = true,
                                             },
                                     .exit_code_on_error = {
                                             .python = 0,
                                     }};
```

After:

```c
struct ApplicationState app_state = {
    .signal = {
        .use_crash_handler = true,
        .use_abort_handler = true,
    },
    .exit_code_on_error = {
        .python = 0,
    },
};
/*   ^ notice trailing comma on the second last line! */
```

Answer (score 1):

The primary thing you need is:

```
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: All
```

You could instead set the overall style to `WebKit`, because that sets `BreakBeforeBinaryOperators` to `All`.

Clearly, clang-format must see the `.` as a binary operator. I'm not sure if it *should*, but that's what it seems to do.

---

I tested this with clang-format 6.0.0. Presumably newer versions would work the same, but I haven't tested so I can't be sure.