# clang-format always indent struct initiallizers

Tags: c, code-formatting, clang-format

i have a very strange behavior with my current `.clang-format` file.

here is the file:

```
---
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
ColumnLimit: 200
IndentWidth: 4
UseTab: Always
TabWidth: 4
BreakBeforeBraces: Linux
```

considering this example C code it will format it as expected:

```
struct foo {
    char a;
    int b;
};

static const struct foo data[] = {
    {'a', 1},
    {'b', 2},
    {'c', 3},
};
```

however if i add an empty `{}` element in my array, clang-format will put the complete array initialization in one line:

```
struct foo {
    char a;
    int b;
};

static const struct foo data[] = {{'a', 1}, {'b', 2}, {'c', 3}, {}};
```

is there a way to tell `clang-format` to allow an empty element in a line and to correctly format the code as in the first example?

**EDIT1:**

as Nullndr suggested adding a traling `,` will get clang-format to create the right formatting.

however lets rephrase the question: is there a way to tell clang-format to do the formatting correct even without trailing `,`?

**EDIT2:**
it seems this is a bug in clang-format. i reported it here: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/61585

Comment: What happens if you put a colon? `{..., {},}`

Comment: yes, this will render it corectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, even with version 15 this is still not possible and there is nothing about this on the [docs](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html).

This is not a problem just with arrays, but with structs too, take a look:

```c
static const struct foo data = {'a', 1}; // see the missing `,`
```

If you put a comma, it correctly indent the struct:

```c
static const struct foo data = {
  'a',
  1, // see the trailing `,` 
};
```

Here on SO there are a lot of responses about this, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65135005/10503039) for example.

Another trick is to put a comment at the end of the row:

```c
static const struct foo data[] = {
  {'a', 1}, //
  {'b', 2}, //
  {'c', 3}  //
};
```

I never used this since I find it ugly

Comment: thank you. yes it seems that clang-format always expects a trailing comma