# Start each << from a new line in C++ with clang-format

Tags: c++, indentation, clang-format

Consider the following piece of C++ code:

```cpp
void foo() {
  std::cout << "Hello, "
    << "world!"
    << std::endl;
}
```

When I run `clang-format` without any style options, I get this:

```cpp
void foo() {
  std::cout << "Hello, "
            << "world!" << std::endl;
}
```

How to obtain the following result (each `<<` starts on its own line)?

```cpp
void foo() {
  std::cout << "Hello, "
            << "world!"
            << std::endl;
}
```

One [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34362422/1800052) is to terminate each line with `//`:

```cpp
void foo() {
  std::cout << "Hello, " //
    << "world!" //
    << std::endl; //
}
```

But is that possible to achieve such indentation by using [style options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) only?

Comment: `std::cout << "Hello, " << "world!\n";` Problem solved :-)

Comment: `\n` is more common than `std::endl`

Comment: `std::endl` is solely for the purpose of demonstration; the same applies if you use variables (e.g., `const std::string s = "world!"`).

Answer (score 3):

https://reviews.llvm.org/D80950 explains why it does this. When clang-format was originally written, a decision was made that if literal strings were streamed next to each other i.e.

```
os << "A" << "B"
```

they would be put on a separate line

```
os << "A" 
   << "B"
```

but for anything else, they wouldn't

```
os << "A" << i << "B"
```

There really isn't any control over this. Breaking after every streaming operator could be considered too much.

```
os << "A"
   << i
   << "B"
```