# How to format << in ClangFormat

Tags: clang, clang-format

How to format a line like this:

```
test << "a" << "b" << "c";
```

into this:

```
test << "a" 
     << "b"
     << "c"
```

using ClangFormat?

Comment: What is this statement supposed to do? I do not think you can achieve it, anyway.

Comment: The statement is supposed to insert some strings into a std::ostringstream (where the ostringsteam is in my example "test")

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67809683/start-each-from-a-new-line-in-c-with-clang-format I don't think there is a solution.