# How can I allow extra line break when the line is not too long?

Tags: clang-format

I have an `if` condition of the following form:

```
if ((foo == cond1)
   && (bar == cond2))
{
  // Code
}
```

Without the break inside the condition, the line is not too long for `clang-format`. Thus it is corrected as:

```
if ((foo == cond1) && (bar == cond2))
{
  // Code
}
```

How can I let `clang-format` accept extra breaks in this situation (and if possible, other contexts) ?

I currently use LLVM's default configuration.

Comment: Please read: [Clang-format line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656800/clang-format-line-breaks), and tell what info you are missing....

Comment: I didn't stumble across this post, the proposed solutions are not satisfying but I understand that there aren't satisfying solutions.
I guess I will accept the generic formatting instead of these ad-hoc ones.